# Socket.io is not emmiting event even if socket is connected in react node app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

#### Server.js

```js
const express=require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const IOServer = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(IOServer);

const port=process.env.PORT||4000;
const IO_PORT=process.env.IO_PORT||5000;
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit("hello", "world");
    socket.on("hello",(arg)=>console.log(arg))
});

app.listen(port,(err)=>{
    if(!err) 
        console.log("server is started..@ PORT "+port)
    else console.log("Problem....!!!!")
});
IOServer.listen(IO_PORT,(err)=>{
    if(!err) 
        console.log("IO server is started..@ PORT "+IO_PORT)
    else console.log("IO server Problem....!!!!")
})
```

#### React client

```js
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io(`http://localhost:${process.env.REACT_APP_IO_PORT || 5000}`);

// in useEffect()
socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log('Socket connected',socket.id); 
});

socket.on("hello", (arg) => {
  console.log(arg); // world
});
socket.emit("hello","world")
console.log("Connecting the socket")
```

I am getting `A socket connected!` on the backend server-side, but nothing logs on the front end.
I also tried `io.connect(url)` instead of `io()`, but nothing worked.

[https://github.com/ats1999/problem-repo](https://github.com/ats1999/drone-air-mission-planning)

Comment: Move socket.on("hello"..., inside socket.on("connect".., emit and listen when connection is ready

Comment: `socket.on("connect", () => {
            console.log('Socket connected',socket.id); 
            socket.on("cords",(data)=>{
                console.log(data)
            });
            socket.on("hello", (arg) => {
                console.log(arg); // world
            });
            socket.emit("hello","world")
        });`

Comment: Still, this is not working